# Data Structure for faster contains() operation?

Tags: java, data-structures, time-complexity, contains

In the problem , I parse the input (integer) and simultaneously check if it exists in the data structure , if not then add it.

Input is - 2 integers separated by space of size >=1 and <= 1000000

I tried using `HashMap` , `TreeMap` (`put()` and `containsValue()` method)- but it seems they are taking too much time. (5 out of 10 test  cases are exceeding time limit)

When using `ArrayList`(add() and contains() method) - (4 out of 10 test cases exceeded the time limit)

These operations are to be performed inside 2nd for loop , inside an if condition.

iterations may varies as follows : -

1st for loop - 1 to 10

2nd for loop - 1 to 100000

so i guess for higher order iteration in 2nd loop it exceeds time limit.

Is there any other way i could perform this task in lesser time .

**Problem :**

A Monk encounters N ponds and at each pond a fooditem(input 1) and a pokemon(input 2) is found .

The monk can feed the item at the i'th pond to the Pokemon at the pond if the type matches. Monk may have to carry some food items with him before leaving so as to feed all the Pokemons. Help him find the number of items he must carry, to be to able to pass through the land safely.

**Explanation**

At First Pond he gets item of type1 and feeds it to the Pokemon of type1.

At Second Pond he gets item of type 2 and feeds it to the Pokemon of type2.

At Third Pond he gets item of type 3 ,but the Pokemon is of type4 . Hence, he 
has to bring a food item of type 4 with him.

At Fourth Pond he gets item of type 4. He already has a item of type 3 and feeds it to the Pokemon.

At Fifth Pond he gets items of type 2. He already has a item of type 4 and feeds it to the Pokemon at this pond

```
class TestClass {
public static void main(String args[] ) throws Exception {

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    int T = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    if(T<=10 && T>=1)   {
    for (int i = 0; i < T; i++) {
       int count=0;
       int numOfPonds = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        if(numOfPonds<=100000 && numOfPonds>=1){  
       String[] str ;
       Map m = new HashMap();
        //List l = new ArrayList();

        for(int j=0 ; j< numOfPonds ;j++)
                {   
                    str = br.readLine().split(" ");
                    int foodType = Integer.parseInt(str[0]);
                    int PokeType = Integer.parseInt(str[1]);
                    if(foodType<=1000000 && PokeType<=1000000 && foodType>=1 && PokeType>=1 && foodType != PokeType){

                        m.put(j,foodType);

                    //l.add(foodType);

                        //if(!(l.contains(PokeType)))
                    if(!(m.containsValue(PokeType)))                        
                                    count++;

                    //else if(l.contains(PokeType))
                    else if(m.containsValue(PokeType))
                        {
                            m.values().remove(PokeType);
                            //  l.remove(Integer.valueOf(PokeType));
                            }

                    }
                }
        }
       System.out.println(count);
      }
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: Using a binary tree structure may be your best bet depending on the values being input. That'll run in O(logn) on average

Comment: What not use a HashSet<Integer> if you only storing a number

Comment: @user2341963 duplicate entries are to be allowed

Comment: In the problem description you're saying check if it exists, if not then add. Doesn't that mean duplicate entries are not allowed?

Comment: if it exists then there is another condition , where it may or may not be added .

Comment: Use a boolean array with 1000000 elements, each element indicated whether the index value exist or not.

Comment: Why do you search for `containsValue()`. Try to keep the `Integer` as a key in `HashMap` and use `containsKey()`. That will be much faster.

Comment: Sounds like you're using an inefficient method to construct your data structure and then probably search. Show your code.

Comment: @CodeBender Why in the world reinvent HashSet?

Comment: @chrylis, because he needs duplicate values... He can keep integer as key.. and no of times it occurred as value... Read the comments above...

Comment: ok i'll add the code , and explain the question in a little more detail

Comment: `if(!(m.containsValue(PokeType))) ... else if(m.containsValue(PokeType)) ...` Why bother search twice?

Comment: okay consider it else -_-

Comment: And `HashMap.containsValue` performs _linear search_. You should reconsider what the key type should be.

Comment: Map.containsValue() is very expensive -- it must traverse the entire map.  Instead, invert the map so that you can use Map.containsKey(); maps are optimized for this type of operation, so this is very fast.

Comment: @timrau  tried TreeMap also , i guess it uses binary search right ? still same result

Comment: You're missing the point.  Searching for values in a map is _expensive_.  Searching for keys in a map is _cheap_.

Comment: so i'll try using containsKey() then , thanks @JimN

Comment: Don't forget to reverse the parameter order when calling `m.put()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following is the code that passed all the test cases within the time limit.

As mentioned by **Codebender** and **JimN** , I implemented `containsKey()` method that proved to be faster than `containsValue()` .

Plus , for duplicates , incremented and changed the values in Map.

```
class TestClass {
public static void main(String args[] ) throws Exception {

BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

int T = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
if(T<=10 && T>=1)   {
for (int i = 0; i < T; i++) {
   int count=0;
   int numOfPonds = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    if(numOfPonds<=100000 && numOfPonds>=1){  
   String[] str ;

Map<Integer,Integer> map = new HashMap<Integer,Integer>();
    for(int j=0 ; j< numOfPonds ;j++)
            {   
                str = br.readLine().split(" ");
                int foodType = Integer.parseInt(str[0]);
                int PokeType = Integer.parseInt(str[1]);

                if(foodType<=1000000 && PokeType<=1000000 && foodType>=1 && PokeType>=1 && foodType != PokeType){

                if(map.containsKey(foodType))
                {
                    int x = map.get(Integer.valueOf(foodType));
                    x++;
                    map.put(foodType,x);
                }
                else
                {   map.put(foodType,1);
                }

                if(!(map.containsKey(PokeType)))                        
                                count++;

                else 
                    {   int x = map.get(Integer.valueOf(PokeType));
                        x--;

                        if(x==0)
                        map.remove(PokeType);

                        else
                        map.put(PokeType,x);

                        }

                }
            }
     }
   System.out.println(count);
  }
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not fully know what you are trying to do other than looking at your code. But this will give you quickest response . As far as finding the value in HashSet goes it will be O(1) .

Try this below

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class SalesTracking {
public static void main(String args[] ) throws Exception {

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    int T = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    if(T<=10 && T>=1)   {
    for (int i = 0; i < T; i++) {
       int count=0;
       int numOfPonds = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        if(numOfPonds<=100000 && numOfPonds>=1){  
       String[] str ;
       //Map m = new HashMap();
       Set m = new HashSet();
        for(int j=0 ; j< numOfPonds ;j++)
                {   
                    str = br.readLine().split(" ");
                    int foodType = Integer.parseInt(str[0]);
                    int PokeType = Integer.parseInt(str[1]);
                    if(foodType<=1000000 && PokeType<=1000000 && foodType>=1 && PokeType>=1 && foodType != PokeType){
                        m.add(foodType);
                    if(!(m.contains(PokeType)))                        
                                    count++;
                    else if(m.contains(PokeType))
                        {   m.remove(PokeType);

                        }

                    }
                }
        }
       System.out.println(count);
      }
    }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of a [*bloom filter*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter) and a `Set<T>`.

> A Bloom filter is a space-efficient probabilistic data structure ... that is used to test whether
> an element is a member of a set. False positive matches are possible,
> but false negatives are not – in other words, a query returns either
> "possibly in set" or "definitely not in set".

The algorithm:

1. First query the *bloom filter*, if it return "definitely not in set" then the element is new.
2. If the *bloom filter* returns "possibly in set" then call `Set<T>.contains()` to be sure about containment.

*Bloom filter* Java implementation: https://guava.dev/releases/23.0/api/docs/com/google/common/hash/BloomFilter.html 
Related article about usage: https://www.baeldung.com/guava-bloom-filter